# Flutter dart add list to children

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new on dart, I just want to add a list of my data using map (**store.state.availablePage.map**) to the children of ListView, but I already have some item on the ListView.

Here the sample code I want :

```
class MgDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreBuilder<AppState>(
      builder: (context, store) {
        return Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Title"),
              store.state.availablePage.map((value) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("Title"),
                  onTap: () {},
                );
              }).toList(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me how I can achieve that?

Update: the code above is not compiled.

**Updates Dart Lang version > 2.2.2, can be achieve using below code** :

```
class MgDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreBuilder<AppState>(
        builder: (context, store) {
        return Drawer(
            child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
                Text("Title"),
                ...store.state.availablePage.map((value) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text("Title"),
                    onTap: () {},
                );
                }).toList(),
            ],
            ),
        );
        },
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing? Any error?

Comment: the code above not compiled

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ListView is having `Text(Widget)` and a `Array of ListTile(Array of Widgets)` which means `ListView(children: [Widget, [Widget]])`.

But it should be `ListView(children: [Widget1, Widget2, Widget3,...])`. Below code might help

```
 class MgDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StoreBuilder<AppState>(
          builder: (context, store) {
            List<Widget> list = store.state.availablePage.map((value) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("Title"),
                onTap: () {},
              );
            }).toList();
            list.insert(0, Text("Title"));
            return Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: list,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is ok on compile but I got on error when running it. "type Text is not subtype of type ListTile of element"

Comment: type of list should be `List<Widget>`. Can you please check/

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason someone is unable to use "..." operator, there is also another solution. It is not as elegant as "..." operator, but it also works.

You can just use ..addAll(list) at the end of the list.

Here is how it would look like in given example:

```
class MgDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreBuilder<AppState>(
      builder: (context, store) {
        return Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Title"),
            ]..addAll(store.state.availablePage.map((value) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("Title"),
                onTap: () {},
              );
            }).toList(),),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```